# Excel VBA: How do I run this code only on one sheet only (sheet9) , instead the one that's active?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Test()
Dim r As Long
For r = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If IsNumeric(Cells(r, 3)) Then Rows(r).Delete
Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it a worksheet object, and then qualify your references with it.

```
Sub Test(sh as Worksheet)
  Dim r As Long
  For r = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If IsNumeric(sh.Cells(r, 3)) Then sh.Rows(r).Delete
  Next r
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
Test Worksheets(1)
```

or:

```
Test sheet9
```